# Print documents on both sides of the page without using the "double-sided printing" function and not on the first page

Tags: printing, printer, epson-workforce

I did some research on this and figured out how to print documents from the first page (first print the odd and then the even pages). But I still have a few more questions:

1. How do I print the document starting on the even page (do I print the even pages first or vice versa?)
2. How do I print the document as a book if I use the "two pages per sheet" feature?

Comment: This is application dependent. Which application are you printing from? The easiest way to start printing on the second sheet is to add a blank page at the beginning of the document.